# NetworkManager crashes when asking for wifi password in new user account. 16.04

Tags: wireless, users

I created a new user account for a friend to use my laptop. When attempting to connect to my WiFi the network icon in the top bar disappears and it does not connect. I ran `journalctl -f` while doing it again to see if we can capture the error, this is the error I saw:

```
Feb 04 08:30:37 samwise gnome-session[2896]: nm-applet-Message: New secrets for eric 1/802-11-wireless-security requested; ask the user
Feb 04 08:30:37 samwise gnome-session[2896]: **
Feb 04 08:30:37 samwise gnome-session[2896]: GLib:ERROR:/build/glib2.0-prJhLS/glib2.0-2.48.2/./glib/gvarianttypeinfo.c:163:g_variant_type_info_check: assertion failed: (info->alignment == 0 || info->alignment == 1 || info->alignment == 3 || info->alignment == 7)
```

Seems like it tries to ask for the password and dies. Anyone seen this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Network Manager -> Edit Connections and make sure that the checkbox "All users can use the connection" is checked.

Comment: I'm I correct in believing this just started happening in Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04?  I don't recall having to do that in the past.  However, now I find this as a very annoying behavior. My clients who have occasions to changer their routers and networks loose the ability to have remote support and have problems learning how to perform these steps every time they connect to a new network name.  Is there some way to configure Network manager to default to this setting for new networks connections?  (All users and Automatic connection?)

Comment: Yes this seems to have worked... Though I can't find any reason behind this. Of course crashing is not the desired behavior, so that's a bug. Second, no one user "owns" a specific wifi connection, so it makes no sense that one user would have to grant another user access to it... wtf?

Comment: Report it as a bug against Network Manager by running `ubuntu-bug network-manager`.